# Docker Django staticfiles are not copied to STATIC_ROOT

Tags: django, docker

I am generating static files for my Django app inside a Docker environment. In the logs, the static files are 'copied'.

```
173 static files copied.
```

However, the static files are not present inside the volume. I print my settings to see this...

```
#settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

print('STATIC_ROOT:', STATICFILES_DIRS)
print('FILES:', os.listdir(STATIC_ROOT))
```

The STATIC_ROOT is empty.

```
STATIC_ROOT: '/usr/src/app/staticfiles'
FILES: []
```

I am using a named volume for the static files. I also execute the `collecstatic` in here.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_database &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear &&
             python manage.py loaddata fixtures/initial.json &&
             gunicorn api.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - application:/usr/src/app
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
    - test-prod.env

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
    restart: always

volumes:
  application:
  static_volume:
```

In my Dockerfile, I create the directory for the staticfiles and copying the source code to the volume.

```
FROM python:3.9-bullseye
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
...
...
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/staticfiles
COPY api /usr/src/app
```

I do not get where the static files are copied. I know they're not in the correct directory where I specified `STATIC_ROOT` since no page are served when I visit the site. It must also show when I print the list directories in the `STATIC_ROOT`.

I have also tried replacing the `STATIC_ROOT` with...

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
]
```

However the static files are also not present in the directory.

Comment: If there is anything at all in `static_volume` then the contents of this volume will hide the contents of the `staticfiles` directory, in both containers.  The only thing that might copy files into the volume is a special case in Docker the first time the volume is used, but I'd avoid relying on it.

Comment: What would be the best solution to generate or copy the static files?

Comment: It looks like you're already using a custom image for the Nginx proxy; in that image, you could use a multi-stage build to run `manage.py collectstatic` and then `COPY` the files into the final image.

Comment: Its like generating it on a dev environment and pushing it to the production?

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM python:3.9-bullseye
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
...
...
COPY api /usr/src/app/
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/api/staticfiles
```